# Naming convention: Lie groups with finitely generated discrete part

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, terminology, lie-groups

Consider a Lie group $G$ and let $G_0$ be the connected component of the identity.
Then $G_{\mathrm{dis.}}:=G/G_0$ is a discrete group.
We are writing a (physics) article in which finite-dim. Lie groups play a role for which $G_{\mathrm{dis.}}$ is finitely generated and wondering whether there is a common name associated to such groups that we should use. So far we couldn't find such a name, but that of course does not mean that it doesn't exist.

So is there a conventional name given to those Lie groups for which $G_{\mathrm{dis.}}$ is finitely generated?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I have added the small bit of context that I can. After all it is a purely semantic question.

Comment: $G/G_0$ is often called the *component group* of $G$, though I'm not sure if "Lie groups with finitely generated component group" is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the same class as the class of **[compactly generated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactly_generated_group#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20compactly%20generated,one%20of%20its%20compact%20subsets.)** Lie groups: A topological group $G$ is called **compactly generated** if there exists a compact $K\subset G$, which generates the entire group $G$. Proving that the two classes are the same is a nice exercise. The key is that every connected Lie group is compactly generated.